# Content Search Webpart not displaying results on the page on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, content-search-web-part

Content search web part is not returning the results when added to the page in SharePoint Online. Even though I am able to see the results in the 'Search Result Preview'. But when I click OK and save the page it is still not showing the results.

Search are returning results in Search Query Tool as well. Also there is no error with display template, I am using OOB display template.

Am  I Missing anything ? Any features that i need to activate ?

Comment: Hello Dhaval, the same thing happened to me now, but it's on a different site collection than the one I'm testing now so I know it's searchable, and the query test returns items but the page is not showing anything, did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, I am allowing custom scripts from tenant SharePoint admin and will test. believe it takes 24 hours to update so need to play the waiting game. Link for how to change settings : https://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2018/10/28/enable-custom-script-on-modern-sharepoint-sites-using-powershell/ Cannot(can) believe Microsoft have let this one slip through the net without providing a solution or workaround

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure if search site set to searchable and also can you re-index site and wait for 24hrs to get results back.

check under site settings → search → search and offline availability.

Answer (score 0):

An additional issue that really can cause a lot of head scratching is the way that the duplication detection algoritm works. As a general rule I will recommend that "remove duplicates" is Always set to No in the search result web parts

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have allowed to display duplicates.